# I can't install new AMD drivers, problems with fglrx

Tags: drivers, amd-radeon

I am trying to install new drivers for AMD since my computer is pretty old and maybe this could help with some graphics stuff.

This is the driver I'm downloading: AMD Catalyst™ **15.9 Proprietary Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 Video Driver for Graphics Accelerators**

That's the package: **fglrx_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb**

And when I run it with **GDebi package installer**, I get this:

`Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: fglrx-core`

So, I go to their page where they give info on how to fix dependencies and stuff and run these commands:

`#sudo apt-get build-dep lib32gcc1`

`Output is: Reading package lists... Done E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list`

And `#sudo apt-get build-dep lib32gcc1` gives the same

And then `$sudo apt-get fglrx-updates` gives

`E: Invalid operation fglrx-updates`

I don't know what to do, I have tried purging fglrx as some people have suggested, then tried to reinstall it but whenever I try to it's as if the package doesn't exist. Help? I am most likely missing something about these drivers, or my computer is too old.

My computer specs:

[image: SPECS]

Comment: As for "You must put some 'deb-src' URIs": see https://askubuntu.com/questions/158871/how-do-i-enable-the-source-code-repositories . As for "Invalid operation fglrx-updates": you forgot the word "install".

Comment: Added 'install' and this is what I get sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fglrx-updates

Comment: Trying to install fglrx gives this:

sudo apt-get install fglrx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fglrx

Answer (score 0):

**Tl;DR: You don't need and shouldn't try to install AMD proprietary drivers. There aren't any AMD proprietary drivers for legacy hardware in Linux and the only drivers that supports such hardware - `radeon` - is already included iin the kernel.**

Since many years ago AMD made its graphics driver open-source and since then they've been added to the kernel like any other open-source drivers.

AMD graphics drivers are automatically selected during the OS installation according to the hardware detected, `radeon` for legacy hardware or `amdgpu` for currently supported hardware.

DON'T try to install the old `fglrx` because it can't possibly be installed in newer and/or older kernels since ~7 years ago!

For completeness I should add AMD does provide an additional proprietary "overlay" driver - `amdgpu-pro` - ONLY for current hardware but "normal" users shouldn't bother with this because it brings nothing to the regular usage, including gaming, as thoroughly tested by experts (e.g. Phoronix). It may improve performance in very specific scenarios (3D modeling/rendering, cryptomining, ...) but not for the vast majority of usages.

Your hardware runs with `radeon` therefore you can't and obviously shouldn't try to install the aforementioned proprietary "overlay" because it'll fail (hardware not supported). The best and only driver for you is already installed and running, no user actions required. `radeon`is what supports your hardware, end of the story and end of the road for any legacy AMD graphics hardware.